# Android Phonegap - implements a like button

Tags: facebook, cordova, button, facebook-like

Anyones known a method of implements facebook like button on app builded with phonegap 2.2 ??  this code for HTML5 don't works:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script>(function(d, s, id) {   
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];   
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;   
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;   
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=443968115691947";   
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/QueBajeDios" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

This generated by like button - developers webpage.

And this other for IFRAME also doesn't work:

```html
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FQueBajeDios&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=21&amp;appId=443968115691947" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I need any reference for know methods of this implements...  but I don't found anything on Google...

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this plugin made for Phonegap and Facebook. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: I don't think this plugin supports versions 2.2 you may need to upgrade.